# Unmounted directories still behave like mounted - NFS Server Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nfs, mount, unmount

I am working on two virtual machines, running Ubuntu 14.04. So, one VM is the server and the other the client. Here's what I've done till now:

**Server VM:**

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server

sudo nano /etc/exports
```

I added:

```
/home/mnt_dir *(rw,sync)

sudo chmod 777 /home/mnt_dir

service nfs-kernel-server restart
```

**Client VM:**

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common

sudo mount -v -t nfs server_ip:/home/mnt_dir /home/mnt_dir
```

and everything works fine. Then I need to unmount them so I run the command on the client VM:

```
sudo umount -l /home/mnt_dir/
```

Just to be sure I run the above command again and the output message is

```
umount: /home/mnt_dir: not mounted
```

The problem is that although I get the above message, changes on the one VM still apply to the other VM, like the directories are still mounted. Why is this happening?

edit: I noticed that in order to mount/umount work properly, I need to run a simple cd command. Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I noticed that in order to mount/umount work properly, I need to run a simple cd command. Any ideas about that?

If you are currently in a directory that is within a mounted filesystem and you try to unmount it, you normally get an error message that the fielsystem is busy the effect of this is it  can't be unmounted e.g.

```
$ umount: /mnt/data: device is busy
```

Note what the documentation says about `unmount -l` it is important.

When you issue a `cd` command with no parameters it has a special meaning (which you can look up in the documentation).

The upshot of the `cd` command is that the filesystem becomes not busy and can be unmounted.